# Adding elements to LinkedList fluently in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, fluent

I'm lookig for a way (ideally only with Java SDK classes) to inline adding elements to a LinkedList in Java, to convert

```
LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
linkedList.add("b");
linkedList.addAll(List.of("c", "d"));
linkedList.addFirst("a");
linkedList.addLast("e");
```

to something like

```
new LinkedList<>().add("b").addAll(List.of("c", "d")).addFirst("a").addLast("e");
```

Comment: There is no "fluent style" to add like that. You would have to create helper methods that take the list as argument as well. `addTo(list, "b").addAllTo(list, ...).addFirstTo(list, "a").addLastTo(list, "e")`

Comment: @Zabuzard there is a lib http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Data_Structure_How_to/List/Subclass_ArrayList_with_fluent_api.htm but i don't want to include them just for this class

Comment: @cnmuc But this is not `java.util.LinkedList`, it is a self-written class that provides such methods. There is no way to make this happen with Javas built-in classes.

Comment: @Unmitigated i find it more readable. and yes, i'm adding these elements manually. also, in my many years of software development i rarely saw code using the boolean result of addAll (what you should actually do)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning Kotlin as an option that would give you the possibility to add extension methods to existing classes in hindsight. But Java itself cant do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** "*fluent style*" to add like that. What you are asking is not possible with the methods available in `LinkedList` (as of today).

### Helper

However, you can technically create your own helper methods that take the list as argument as well. Something like:

```java
// Same for addAllTo, addFirstTo, addLastTo
public static <E> LinkedList<E> addTo(LinkedList<E> list, E element) {
  list.add(element);
  return list;
}
```

Then you could use it as:

```java
var list = new LinkedList<String>();
addTo(list, "b")
  .addAllTo(list, List.of("c", "d"))
  .addFirstTo(list, "a")
  .addLastTo(list, "e")
```

There is no way to add the list itself to the fluent-chain as well, since you need to be able to *name* it.

You also can not get rid of the `list`-argument, since you can not add the methods to `LinkedList` itself.

### Delegate extension

Another option, but this is kinda ugly, would be to create a new `LinkedList` class, which just delegates all calls to the actual. So something like:

```java
public class FluentLinkedList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
  private final LinkedList<E> delegate = new LinkedList<>();

  @Override
  public boolean add(E element) {
    return delegate.add(element);
  }

  // Override and delegate all other List methods as well ...

  // Then finally add your own extensions
  public FluentLinkedList<E> addFluent(E element) {
    add(element);
    return this;
  }

  // ...
}
```

You can not get rid of the original `add` method though, unless you want to break compatibility with the `List` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a class which extends LinkedList which provides the desired behavior:

```
class FluentList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {
    FluentList <T> with(T element) {
        this.add(element);
        return this;
    }
    FluentList <T> with(Collection<T> elements) {
        this.addAll(elements);
        return this;
    }
    FluentList <T> withFirst(T element) {
        this.addFirst(element);
        return this;
    }
    FluentList <T> withLast(T element) {
        this.addLast(element);
        return this;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to fluently add elements with the `with` prefix while leaving the `add`-functionality as-is from LinkedList. E.g:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FluentList<String> strings = new FluentList<String>()
                .with("a")
                .with(List.of("b", "c"))
                .withFirst("d")
                .withLast("e");
        strings.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```